# PSTricks and pdfTex in the Elsevier system

Tags: pdftex, pstricks

I am trying to submit a LaTeX file to Elsevier journal. The .tex file is working well when I use xelatex or PdfTex with ps->pdf. The elsevier system is giving the following error that I get also when using PdfTex alone:

```
    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX)
(preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.7.12) 9 JAN 2020 11:50
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.

! Undefined control sequence.
\c@lor@to@ps ->\PSTricks
_Not_Configured_For_This_Format
l.381 }
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: How about converting your `pstricks` code to stand-alone images and then uploading them together with your article. One of the [recommendations](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions) is to "keep it simple."

Comment: is there an easy way to convert 'pstricks' code to images?

Comment: Use package `auto-pst-pdf ` and run your document with `pdflatex --shell-escape <file>` Then you'll get a file which holds all PStricks images as single pdf pages.

Comment: it is working, thank you